# How to get numpy function (ufunc) arguments

Tags: python, numpy

```
>>> import inspect
>>> import numpy as np
>>> inspect.getargspec(np.abs)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\inspect.py", line 815, in getargspec
    raise TypeError('{!r} is not a Python function'.format(func))
TypeError: <ufunc 'absolute'> is not a Python function
```

So `inspect` doesn't return arguments for `numpy` function, because it does not recognize it as function, while `numpy` doesn't seem to have helper function that would return function's arguments.

Does anyone know how to get arguments for arbitrary numpy function?

Comment: All ufuncs have the same signature. The only differences are the number of in and outputs, and those are available as `.nin` and `.nout`

Comment: @seberg it would be nice if you posted your comment as the right answer since it solved the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### copied from the comments above --> credits to Seberg

All ufuncs have the same signature. The only differences are the number of in and outputs, and those are available as

```
.nin
```

and

```
.nout
```

–  seberg Mar 27 '13 at 20:27

https://stackoverflow.com/users/455221/seberg

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer - it was not mine, so the credits must go to the author; this was my modest contribution to the backlog of unanswered questions.